# How do I run ruby commands in my bash script without getting "ruby: command not found"

Tags: ruby, bash

my script=

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ************************BEGIN LOG******************************>>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME">>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1
ruby /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/aapxen01.rb>>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1
ruby /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/apvdbs03.rb>>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1
ruby /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/aapxen02.rb>>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1

echo end log entry>>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/vmbackup.log 2>&1
```

my log=

```
************************BEGIN LOG******************************
09/28/2010 11:10:01 aapsan01.boingoboingo.local
/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh: line 5: ruby: command not found
/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh: line 6: ruby: command not found
/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh: line 7: ruby: command not found
end log entry
```

my crontab this runs from:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=admins@boingoboingo.com
HOME=/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR
#sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
05 01 * * * /root/backup_scripts/run_backups.sh
22 11 * * * /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh
```

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question, but do you have ruby installed?

Comment: It occurs to me that I should mention that I have this running from crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the directory that ruby lives in into your PATH.
`PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH"; export PATH`

Comment: You might also want to store this line in your `.bashrc` to avoid typing it each time you open up a terminal.

Comment: If the script is run from cron or some other background method, it won't inherit your PATH, so you need to make sure the PATH is set in the script.

Comment: Do I just add a line to the script like this? PATH=/usr/bin/ruby and put that under #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: @micha, you need to write it the way I did above: `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH;export PATH`

Comment: And of course, it will depend where ruby is installed on your system - I have mine in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute pathname of the interpreter e.g. `/usr/bin/ruby`, or check why it does not appear in the `$PATH` of the environment of the user owning the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the full path for ruby?

Chris